# Elite: Dangerous. Maximum number of players?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Which is the maximum number of players, that can be in the game in the same time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I have read Elite Dangerous will use different instances. And each instance can hold up to 32 players.

[source](http://forums.frontier.co.uk/showpost.php?p=322442&postcount=8)

> Remember that instances are basically a bubble around your ship that
>   is defined by your scanner/visual range. Although the size is somewhat
>   adaptable. This means that there can be players in one instance and
>   another group of players in another instance some distance away. If
>   one player from the first instance starts to travel towards the
>   seconds instance the players in the first instance will eventually
>   drop of his radar due to distance and the other players will
>   eventually come into view. So if the system works as intended this
>   will feel seamless from the players point of view.

[source 2](http://forums.frontier.co.uk/showpost.php?s=9811b2f4368ce7cc7b45c586a30be399&p=322407&postcount=3)

> And it will be heavily instance in that regard. There might be
>   hundreds, if not thousands of players in your vicinity at any one time
>   but you will only ever see 31 other human players plus AI pilots. This
>   might change as FD make further improvements to the networking model.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thats mean I can see maximum 31 other human players? But the total number of all the players online has no limit?

Comment: @MikroDel see edits:)

Answer (score 5):

Everyone is connected to the same game world, there is no global limit.
There is however a limit how many you can see within your radar range (32 currently), which is limited because of the twitch based nature of the combat system.

Comment: Why someone gave him -1? And without any explanation?

Comment: If  you not agree with this answer - please explain why

Comment: where have you find the information about "twitch based nature of the combat system"?